# Failing APNS for Independent WatchOS6 app

Tags: node.js, swift, ios13, watchos-6

After setting up a new independent WatchOS6 app, which now supports push notifications, getting the device to request the user for push notifications and capturing the push token. I can’t get my server to send a push notification.

With all the correct credentials and P8 set up on my NodeJS server, I have tried to push messages to the device... This is the error all the time:

**Status 400** - `DeviceTokenNotForTopic` - Which according to Apple’s documentation, means that the Topic (BundleId of the app) is wrong. But in this case it is not.

Tried 2 different NPM packages (for elimination)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications

https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn

Both providing me with the same issue.

Has anyone successfully managed to complete a Independent WatchOS app with APNs? What am I missing

———

**Update**

To test the node service, a further 2 tests have been made:

1. Created a new app, iOS this time, with the same Bundle Identifier, using the pushToken and sending a message the service was **successful**
2. Created a new app, another watchOS, with a different Bundle Identifier, this was again rejected but the APNs for the same `DeviceTokenNotForTopic` issue.

To test production, the only way current is to submit to the store for App Store review. TestFlight option is currently not available for the Watch and there is no way to install a production ad-hoc `.ipa` manually. Once it is in the store I will continue with further tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem has been solved.

Xcode has a couple of issues, if you rely on Xcode to sort out your certificates in the developer portal then please don't.

I have been in touch with support and after a few days back and forth with logs it has been made aware that:

1. Apple's documentation for Independent WatchOS applications does not state *anywhere* that the `topic` (which is the bundle id) should be the one ending in **.watchkitapp**
2. Xcode does not allow you to add the Push Notification Capability to the **.watchkitapp** thus meaning it never creates the AppId in your developer portal.

The solution to the problem, I had, was to manually go to the developer portal and add the **.watchkitapp** AppId and create the certificates, thus allowing my p8 certificate on the server to allow pushes to that particular application.

Comment: I am using https://www.apnstester.com/apns/ to test.  In apntester.com, Its showing 'Sent successfully', but not receiving push notification on watch.  any idea ? ( enabled push development for both watchapp and watchappextension. In Xcode, we can't enable Push for watchapp, only for watchappextension. In apntester.com, used certificate of watchapp. Getting error if we use certificate of watchappextension)

Comment: You need to go to your developer account and manually add the certificate to the .watchkitapp id and create certificates

Comment: Yes I created push certificate for the watchkitapp in developer account and using that certificate to send push notifications

Comment: Interesting, just double check that you are using the correct token

Comment: In https://www.apnstester.com/apns/, I am testing with developer push. yes device token is copied from console. Bundle Id given is xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.watchkitapp . And Push certificate of xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.watchkitapp.

Comment: for .watchkitapp, I am using the Certificate Type "APNs Development iOS". hope this is fine

Comment: Hi RichAppz, I am facing the exact same problem. I am using the NodeJS apns2 module and I am getting `DeviceTokenNotForTopic`. I followed your steps to recreate all the certificates manually, including **.watchkitapp**, and made sure to tick the Push Notification option from the list. Then I reissued the p8 certificate. Same result. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I use the token based Authentication to send apns notifications.

Finally I found that I forgot to change the value of `apns-topic` header to watch appid.(form com.xxx to com.xxx.watchkitapp).

Hope this answer can helper others.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question but is something to be aware of.